# Counting program returns blank output

Tags: c++

My goal is to write a C++ program that can read a text file and:

- Count the average number of letters per sentence (the sentences end with ., ! or ?).
- Count the total amount of digits.

The text file would be read with command "./a.out < textfile"

I don't understand why the output is blank.

While the loop runs, it should check each character. If it's a letter, add to the letter count; if it's a number, add to the number count; if it's a ., ! or ?, add to the linecount.

Divide the letters by linecount to find average.

But it's not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int letters; //Total number of letters                                                                                                                                           
  int digits; //Total number of digits                                                                                                                                             
  double sentencecount; //Number of sentences                                                                                                                                      
  float averageletters; //Average number of letters per sentence                                                                                                                   
  int linecount=0; //Count of lines                                                                                                                                                
  char current; //Current character                                                                     
  cin.get(current);
  while (cin) //while receiving input                                                                                                                                              
    {
      digits = 0;
      letters = 0;
      linecount++;
      while (current && '.' || current && '!' || current && '?')        //checks each line                                                                                         
        {
          if (isalpha(current))//counts alphabet characters                                                                                                                        
            letters++;
          if (isdigit(current))//counts digits                                                                                                                                     
            digits++;
          cin.get (current);
        }
      sentencecount = letters/linecount;
      cout << "avg number of letters" << sentencecount << "digits" <<  digits << endl;
      cin.get (current);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The expression `current && '.' || current && '!' || current && '?'` will not work as you seem to expect. Try e.g. `current == '.' || current == '!' || current == '?'` And if that is true, then `isalpha(current)` will *always* be false, as will `isdigit(current)`. So you probably should think a little bit more about your conditions.

Comment: Why would that render alpha current as false?

Comment: Should I eliminate the first While loop and just make the ifs into Whiles instead?

Comment: If you change the loop condition to what I suggest (which is probably not correct, but at least not as bad as your condition) then `current` will *never* be an alpha-numeric character inside the loop.

Comment: You have a big, complicated function that isn't working *at all.* Don't try to fix all the little bugs; start over with a much simpler program that does very little, but works perfectly. Then add complexity a little at a time.

Comment: @Beta 13, but I don't even understand why it's failing.

Comment: It's failing because it's buggy. If you want understand *in detail* exactly what it's doing, you'll have to learn a lot about coding, more than you can learn in five minutes.